# Dynamically display components and data in View .NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an array of objects which I want to be able to display in a View.
For each object I also want to be able to create a container in which the data is held, however I am not sure how to link the HTML with Javascript. At the moment I have a script, which reads in the array of objects and then loops through each object - [script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mScQX.png). However at this point in the for loop, I am trying to add a `<div>` or `<p>` so I can render the information on the screen but I get errors with it.

Another approach I tried was to try render the information in the html like this: [html render approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08X9X.png) - however with this I get run time errors too [run time error for approach 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVVte.png).

I'm not sure how to render html inside the script or how to use data from the script inside the html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Marker
    {
        public string EventName { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult xxx()
        {
            ViewBag.Markers = new List<Marker> { new Marker { EventName = "m1" }, new Marker { EventName = "m2" }, new Marker { EventName = "m3" } };
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var marker in ViewBag.Markers)
{
    <p>@marker.EventName</p>
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. However, just wondering in your Action, is it possible to add the Markers dynamically? For example, at the moment you have a fix number of 3, but is it possible to have a for loop and for each item time it loops, to add a new Marker?

Comment: The data in the View depends on `ViewBag.Markers`,if you want to update the data in the view,you need to update `ViewBag.Markers` and then `return View()`.So that the view will be refreshed.For example,the count of `ViewBag.Markers` is 10, the for loop will show 10 `<p></p>`.